# Why did not Android have Security on Switch Off?

Tags: android, security

I see many people losing their phone complain that their mobile phone is switched off.

Also, thieves once get the phone, immediately switch that off.

Why did not Android allow only the owner of the phone to switch off?

Possibly, asking for Unlock code on trying to switch off.

Comment: Put a lock on the battery cover too?

Comment: You can always disconnect an radio device: just wrap it in aluminum foil and the effect is identical to an offline device: no connection. Therefore your "switch off pin" would be useless.